# QueryString not accepting &amp; - Needs to

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, request.querystring

I need to be able to handle an HTML encoded ampersand in my .Net code.

So the Url is

```
http://myite.com/index.aspx?language=en&amp;Refresh=true
```

There is no way of changing this as it has been generated by something else so this is out of my control.

How can I read the Refresh parameter?

I have tried

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString("Refresh"))
```

but my Request.QueryString("Refresh") is actually empty, so this is pointless, as is Uri.EscapeDataString.

This can't be the first time this has happened, but I'm struggling to find a solution, as most people would say use UrlEncoding, but as I said, the Url is out of my control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`&` in your query string should be `%26`.

Since you can't correct the url.

You can read the refresh value as:

```
Request.QueryString("amp;Refresh");
```

Note that the developer of the service you are using may correct this in future.
It would be good to be ready for that already.

```
var refresh = Request.QueryString("amp;Refresh");
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(refresh))
    refresh = Request.QueryString("Refresh");
```

Comment: So simple! I don't know why I didn't think of it

Comment: I don't think the %26 is the right solution for his example, that will allow you to encode an "&" symbol into your parameter value, I.e., so you can have a parameter such as "?name=bob&jill" by doing "?name=bob%26jill". The url should have an "&" symbol separating the parameters in the first place. Good solution for him using the "amp;Refresh" though!

Answer (score 0):

nunespascal answer pretty much solves your problem. There are some alternate methods.

If its guaranteed that your Refresh parameter is the second key in the QueryStringCollection then you can use `Request.QueryString(1)`

Another method is to do a `Contains` on the QueryStringCollection.

```
If Request.QueryString IsNot Nothing AndAlso Request.QueryString.AllKeys.Count() > 0 Then
    Dim refreshKey = Request.QueryString.AllKeys.FirstOrDefault(Function(nv) nv.Contains("Refresh"))
    If refreshKey IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim refreshValue = Request.QueryString(refreshKey)
    End If
End If
```